# WebStorm test run CodeceptJS Appium

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, webstorm, intellij-plugin, codeceptjs

I want to run tests with WebStorm buttons for Feature/Scenario.

It works with command line with `npx run`

But when I run with WebStrom it looks like it can't understand where is codeceptjs

Where should I add it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: not enough information to see what's wrong. What is a result of running `cucumber-js  --require codecept.localRealAndroidDevice.conf.js --require test/**/*_steps.js --require steps_file.js` in the folder that is specified as a working directory in run configuration?

Comment: @lena So the result is that it runs and finds the core_steps.js file. But in the file there is `inject()` function used and looks like webstorm can't find it. (As attached to screenshot). And this inject function is codeceptJS fucntion.
Or should I somehow add here that I want to run it with codecept?

Comment: @lena Looks like WebStorm doesn't understand how to connect to codeceptjs or that it doesn't understand that it needs codecept to run

Comment: @lena with command line I run it like this: and it works
`npx codeceptjs run -c codecept.localRealiOSDevice.conf.js`

Comment: the IDE shouldn't understand anything, it just runs the command as configured in run configuration. If `cucumber-js  --require codecept.localRealAndroidDevice.conf.js --require test/**/*_steps.js --require steps_file.js` started in terminal works, then the run configuration should work as well. If it doesn't (throw the same referenceerror on `inject()`, then it seems that codeceptjs can't be run with cucumber